# How to get the element from the list?

Tags: c++

I am new for list in c++,
I have a below list, its contains structure. Each structure contains ID and list of values, I need to get the structure based on the ID.

```
Input list= { 
        struct{0,{1,2}}, 
        struct{1,{2,3,4,5,6}}, 
        struct{2,{4,5,6,7,8}},
        struct{3,{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}} 
        }
```

Could you please suggest on this?

Comment: How is `Input` declared?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know i have to find the common values for two structures, I have a ID to get the element. This list is my input, I don't know how this is declared.

Comment: You need to provide a MVCE (minimum verifiable compilable example).  Show us what you have tried.

Comment: use `map` or `unordered_map` instead

Answer (score 1):

You should use [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [std::unsorted_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) for such thing.

`std::map` is a sorted associative container that contains key-value pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{  
    std::map<int,char> example = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'}};

    auto search = example.find(2);
    if(search != example.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found " << search->first << " " << search->second << '\n';
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without compiling code, we can only give high-level answers.

### Direct solution

Write a unary predicate that checks of the ID for a given list item. Use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/ to search and get an iterator to the found item. Dereference the iterator unless it is `list.end()`, in which case no item was found.

### Redesign

As @slawekwin pointed out, a `std::map< IDType, StructureType>` is exactly the right data structure to implement this. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/